# Android check for empty int variable

Tags: android

How can I make this work?

```
int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("image" + passedVar, "drawable", "com.fnesse.beachguide");

if (resId == null) {
    image.setBackgroundResource(resId);
} else {
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.defaultimage);
}
```

I’m getting the correct response back from getResources and I can display an image but if the image doesn’t exist I would like to display a default image instead of nothing?

Cheers,

Mike.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got the if/else flipped. Also, invalid resource ID value is 0, not null. Replace with

```
if (resId != 0)
```

Comment: Perfect, I did have the if/else flipped also! I almost had that after reading some of the little idiosyncrasies of java regarding int and integer. Thanks Seva!